# What does a large negative "Insider Transactions" mean (finviz)?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, stock-markets, financial-literacy

What does a large negative "Insider Trans" on finviz.com mean? In general, does it mean
that the stock is not worth buying now?

For example:
The Zoom Video Communications stock is very popular now. But the finviz shows (https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=ZM):

Insider Trans: -81.66%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that insiders (directors, senior officers) have significantly divested in their Zoom shares. See [on this website](https://www.secform4.com/insider-trading/1585521.htm), which appears to aggregate filings to the SEC on insider trading and which shows significant insider selling activity in the past few months.

As for the stock being worth buying or not, that is your call. Insiders may have information we don't on the stock or this might be the result of other factors (e.g. selling shares that have fully vested around the same period).

Comment: Thank you! But what does that value represent (how is it calculated)? I want to understand what does "Insider Trans = 0%" or "Insider Trans = 100%" mean.

Comment: @Daniel As per the tooltip, it is the 6-minth change in insider ownership.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a documentation for finviz where one can read about the other tooltips?

Comment: @Daniel I don't know this website. I simply hovered over the indicator and the tooltip appeared.